# In a (PHP) framework, what would be a good name for a "manager" class?

Tags: php, naming-conventions

I'm building a PHP framework and my english is not the best.
There are several classes (database abstraction, module, router,...) in my framework and there is a place where they all have to be initialized and executed together.

- What is a good name for a "master" class that initializes and runs all other classes?

Comment: I think the word master doesn't describe its functionality well. It is not like all other classes are childs of it or so.

Comment: Master_Control_Program, or MCP for short.

Comment: It would be interesting to hear more about what this class does exactly. Maybe see some meaningful parts of the code or the function declarations? There might be a fixed expression for it.

Comment: Oh and could somebody please +1 this for me? I'm out of votes.

Comment: I just called it main. The C++ main function fits it perfectly I found out.

Comment: PS - You should pick an answer (if you used one). This is Good practice on StackOverflow - and makes it more likely that people will answer any future questions you have.

Answer (score 7):

BuckarooBonzaiAndTheBootstrapInitiatorRoutine

Comment: Personally, all of my own PHP frameworks use this name somewhere.  For the record, I have written no PHP frameworks.

Answer (score 5):

bootstrap

*adding random text since it won't let me submit otherwise*

Comment: That would have been my name of choice but the bad thing about is that I already have a bootstrapper.php. It loads all class files and initializes the class I'm searching the name for here! :D

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you want to call the framework?

Answer (score 1):

**root**?

*adding random text since it won't let me submit otherwise*

Answer (score 1):

You can name it Delegator.

Answer (score 1):

**What is a good name for a "master" class that initializes and runs all other classes?**

ClassFactory

Answer (score 1):

Why not `TypeYourAppNameHere`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveBase
```

this will be a nice name for the master class i guess

Answer (score 0):

core

*adding random text since it won't let me submit otherwise*

Comment: All the classes together are already the core of my framework - the class that initializes and manages all of them isn't the core.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrapper

*adding random text since it won't let me submit otherwise*

Answer (score 0):

Driver?

*adding random text since it won't let me submit otherwise*

Answer (score 0):

Gennerally that would be the name of your framework.

**$Opue**

would work nicely.  Or you could add a prefix.  `fwOupe.`

Answer (score 0):

I use an `Application` singleton:

```
class Foo 
{
  public function bar()
  {
    $app = Application::getInstance();
    $app->db->query( ... );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will call it `main`. The C++ main function does the same things in some projects - just create instances of some important classes.

Answer (score 0):

GlobalFactory ?

Answer (score 0):

It's an initialisation or bootup routine right? So why not `Boot` or `GlobalInitialiser` or similar?

(adjust to crazy American spelling as needed ;))